# Google Pay processing with MPGS

Tags: asp.net, payment-gateway, payment-processing, google-pay, mastercard

We are working on a project where we want to accept Google Pay payments with MasterCard Payment Gateway Services (MPGS) as the processor. We have all our merchant id from Google and MPGS and are able to get the Google Pay window to open. In the Google Pay window, a message appears, "App is currently running within a test environment". This is the MPGS documentation we are following https://na.gateway.mastercard.com/api/documentation/integrationGuidelines/supportedFeatures/pickPaymentMethod/devicePayments/GooglePay.html

Once we try to initiate the payment, these are the two responses received from MPGS

1. Could not validate signature on Google Pay payment token.
2. Google Pay paymentToken data could not be decrypted

This is some of the code below for getting the Google Pay window

```
const baseRequest = {
    apiVersion: 2,
    apiVersionMinor: 0
};
function initializeGooglePay() {
    const tokenizationSpecification = {
        type: 'PAYMENT_GATEWAY',
        parameters: {
            'gateway': 'mpgs',
            'gatewayMerchantId': 'mpgs-id'
        }
    };

    const allowedCardNetworks = ["AMEX", "DISCOVER", "INTERAC", "JCB", "MASTERCARD", "MIR", "VISA"];
    const allowedCardAuthMethods = ["PAN_ONLY", "CRYPTOGRAM_3DS"];
    const baseCardPaymentMethod = {
        type: 'CARD',
        parameters: {
            allowedAuthMethods: allowedCardAuthMethods,
            allowedCardNetworks: allowedCardNetworks
        }
    };
    cardPaymentMethod = Object.assign(
        { tokenizationSpecification: tokenizationSpecification },
        baseCardPaymentMethod
    );
    paymentsClient = new google.payments.api.PaymentsClient({ environment: document.getElementById('gpEnvironment').value });

    isReadyToPayRequest = Object.assign({}, baseRequest);
    isReadyToPayRequest.allowedPaymentMethods = [baseCardPaymentMethod];
}
```

Comment: Hi mate. Can you please explain how you sent the token we get from GooglePay to MPGS? Was it through the APIs? if yes what API. The docs are very confusing. Would really appreciate if you could help

Comment: @SyedHarisAliGhaznavi if you mind, can you share your email or something I can use to contact you, I will share the details there as it would be a lot of texts.

Comment: sure. haris.4090[@]gmail.com

Comment: Any luck on that mate?

Answer (score 0):

As per MPGS documentation, Google Pay with MPGS Gateway Decryption cannot be tested using TEST MID you need to perform sample transaction with MPGS Prod MID. Please find the documentation reference below. However, you can use the MTF (test-gateway) prod MID (without TEST prefix) to perform successful Google Pay transaction.

https://eu-gateway.mastercard.com/api/documentation/integrationGuidelines/supportedFeatures/pickPaymentMethod/devicePayments/GooglePay.html?locale=en_US

*If the gateway decrypts the payment token, your app needs to specify the gateway ("mpgs") as your payment service provider. This information is needed to allow the payment token generated by Google to be encrypted using the gateway's public key.
**To perform test transactions, you must use your gateway production Merchant ID in production — the test gateway Merchant ID is unable to decrypt payment tokens**.
If the transactions are either APPROVED or DECLINED then the gateway was able to process your test transactions successfully.*